# Frames referencing with a frameset

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child, frame

I want to load the content of this page in the right frame, how do i specify this?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadInCenter(doc1)
    {
       parent.right_bottom.location.href = doc1
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body align="center">
        <a href="javascript:LoadInCenter('myproduct.html')">test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a page with frames which I have created, the left-bar as the navigation pane and the right as the place to display the content. When a user clicks on any of the links on the left it should display it in the middle. How do I achieve this?

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset rows="15%,75%">
    <frame src="loggedin.php">
    <frameset cols="15%,75%">
        <frameset rows="5%,5%,5%,5%,*">
            <frame src="myprofile.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" name="myprofile">
            <frame src="mycompany.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="mycompany">
            <frame src="myproduct.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="myproduct">
            <frame src="market.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="market">      
        <frame src="">
    </frameset>
    </frameset>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: Frameset is not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the question posted above. What I wanted to achieve has been stated. This is to split the frameset into header, side-bar and content area. 
The header is to display logo and others things that as pertaining to the company. This line of code achieves that:

```
<frame src="loggedin.php">
```

The sidebar is to serve as the navigation link, when any of these links is clicked the content should be displayed in the content-area. This line of codes achieve that:

```
<frameset rows="5%,5%,5%,5%,*">
                <frame src="myprofile.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" name="myprofile">
                <frame src="mycompany.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="mycompany">
                <frame src="myproduct.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="myproduct">
                <frame src="market.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="market">      
                <frame src="" >
            </frameset>
```

The last part is the content area which occupies the the rest of the page. This is displayed by this line of code:

```
<frame src="empty.html" noresize="noresize" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" name="centerpage">
```

So, this is the full code. Anyone can copy and paste to see the output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset rows="15%,75%">
    <frame src="loggedin.php">
    <frameset cols="15%,75%">
        <frameset rows="5%,5%,5%,5%,*">
            <frame src="myprofile.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" name="myprofile">
            <frame src="mycompany.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="mycompany">
            <frame src="myproduct.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="myproduct">
            <frame src="market.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" border="0" name="market">      
            <frame src="" >
        </frameset>
        <frame src="empty.html" noresize="noresize" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" name="centerpage">
    </frameset>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: You seem to have just copy/pasted part of your question. Answers should answer question, not repeat parts of it.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and see the difference? We should always make sure we are with a clear mind before making judgment. The full code has to be pasted to help others who might need support like this. Please remove your down-voting.

Comment: Is there a difference? How about you write an *answer* which explains what you changed and why instead of posting a game of spot-the-difference?

Comment: Thanks. You're more informative at this time. I have done the needful.